# filter elements in nested dictionary LINQ

Tags: linq, dictionary, nested

I have the following data structure:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<int>>> data =
            new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<int>>>();
```

I want to filter some of the elements in that dictionary based on value in first element of the list of the inner dictionary.

```
for example:
{legion1
{soldier1, [10,1000]},
{soldier2, [50,1000]}
}
```

Now let's say I want to do foreach loop in which to work only elements where
the value of the first element of the list is less than 20
expected result in the foreach loop is:

```
{legion1{soldier1, [10,1000]}}
```

What I've tried:

I do foreach loop and then I want to use something similar:

```
data.where(x => x.value.where(o => o[0] < 20 ))
```

I always get error that that way is incorrect.

Please tell how can I solve the issue and why my way is failing.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter and iterate over the result set like so:

```
var resultSet = 
         data.ToDictionary(e => e.Key, 
                              e => e.Value.Where(x => x.Value[0] < 20)
                                          .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value)
                          );

foreach(var item in resultSet){
    var key = item.Key; // string
    var values = item.Value; // Dictionary<string, List<int>>
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Georgi I misread your requirement. everything should be as you want now. ;)

Comment: ohh this is great @Aominè. This is even cleaner way. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are applying `operator []` incorrectly. Moreover, since you want to use both `Legion` and `Soldier`, you should construct a tuple combining the two of them:

```
foreach (var t in data.SelectMany(lg => lg.Value.Select(s => new {
    Legion = lg
,   Soldier = s
})).Where(ls => ls.Soldier.Value[0] < 20)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Legion={0} Soldier = {1}", t.Legion.Key, t.Soldier.Key);
}
```

Comment: I tried also that solution but I get more elements in the foreach I guess due to returned result from that anonymous type. Is it possible we change something so that solution will also be possible to use?

Comment: I think I have made mistake. I will try againg tomorrow and provide feedback again.

Comment: @Georgi This approach enumerates soldiers one-by-one, not legions. Each soldier's legion is associated with it through an instance of the anonymous type.